# reducing jquery UI Tabs code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

so I have around 20 Tabs (Pages) with lot of sub-Tabs, all displayed using the similar code below:

I am thinking how can I shrink this code to put in master JS file and use/re-use for each Div??, as those Tabs are loaded.

The roadblock I am hitting is I need to take care of all these Divs, so do I have to really write this same code 20+ times ???

```
    //dynamic tab add/remove
var tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' style=\"float:left;\" role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
tabCounter = 1;

//jquery-ui
var divOneTabs = $( "#divOneTabs" ).tabs({          //same as:  $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
  active: 0
});
$('.tabs').css('height','auto');        //extend height of tab content... not working as of now...

function divOneAddTab(t,c) {
  var label = t,
    id = t + "-" + tabCounter,
    li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
    tabContentHtml = c;

  divOneTabs.find( ".divOneTabs" ).append( li );
  divOneTabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
  //below fixes the tab height issue in jquery-ui
  //divOneTabs.append( '<div id="' + id + '"' + ' class="tabdiv" ' + '><p>' + tabContentHtml + '</p></div>' );
  divOneTabs.tabs( "refresh" );
  tabCounter++;
}

// close icon: removing the tab on click
divOneTabs.delegate( "span.ui-icon-close", "click", function() {
  var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
  $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
  divOneTabs.tabs( "refresh" );
});

divOneTabs.bind( "keyup", function( event ) {
  if ( event.altKey && event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.BACKSPACE ) {
    var panelId = divOneTabs.find( ".ui-tabs-active" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
    $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
    divOneTabs.tabs( "refresh" );
  }
});
//end jquer-ui settings
```

...some function on each page will call their unique divOneAddTab routine and which will then add li to its unique class (same name).

so, this code repeates for divOne, divTwo.....

html:

```
<div id="divOneTabs">
<ul class="divOneTabs">
    <li><a href="#divOneTabsDef">Default</a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" style="float: left;" role="presentation">Remove Tab</span></li>
</ul>
<div id="divOneTabsDef">
    <pre>Sample Output.</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what classes are for.  Everything that has a common behavior should have the same class.  Add a common class, such as `tabContainer` to your tab containers that you can use to reference all tab containers.  Also, the class `divOneTabs` doesn't need to be specific, as the parent id gives you the speicificity you need.  Use id's to identify specific instances, and classes to identify common blocks.

The unique id's for the tab content are generally necessary as they link the tab to the content.

Example:

```
<div id="divOneTabs" class="tabContainer">
  <ul class="divTabs">
    <li><a href="#divOneTabsDef">Default</a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" style="float: left;" role="presentation">Remove Tab</span></li>
    <li><a href="#divOneTabsStuff">Stuff</a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" style="float: left;" role="presentation">Remove Tab</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="divOneTabsDef">
    <pre>Sample Output 1.</pre>
  </div>
  <div id="divOneTabsStuff">
    <pre>Stuff</pre>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="addTab">Add Tab to Div One</button>

<div id="divTwoTabs" class="tabContainer">
  <ul class="divTabs">
    <li><a href="#divTwoTabsDef">Default</a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" style="float: left;" role="presentation">Remove Tab</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="divTwoTabsDef">
    <pre>Sample Output 2.</pre>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="addTab">Add Tab to Div Two</button>
```

For jQuery modifications, use `.tabContainer`:

```
var divTabs = $(".tabContainer").tabs({ 
    active: 0
});
```

Also, add a new argument to the `addTab` function to specify the specific tab container.  If you are adding the tab from within the container, you don't need this, as you can use the context to determine where it is being added.

```
function divAddTab(p, t, c) {
    var label = t,
      id = t + "-" + tabCounter,
      li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label)),
      tabContentHtml = c;

    p.find(".divTabs").append(li);
    p.append("<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>");
    p.tabs("refresh");
    tabCounter++;
}
```

JSfiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pjutycf6/

Comment: thank you fo rthe detail. i have yet to try it, but i am sure it will work.